# Compare dataframe elementtwise while considering values only and ignoring the datatypes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to compare 2 dataframe element wise. The problem i am facing is that the comparison result shows a mismatch even though the values match.

Example below: All the 5 elements between source and target are shown as a mismatch , even though values are exactly the same. On further comparison i could see that datatypes of these columns were different and that could be the reason for they shown as mismtach.

I have tried with both `df1.eq(df2)` as well as `df1 == df2` operator, but both return the same results. Is there any other way to do an element level comparison of only the values while ignoring datatypes?

```
SOURCE: [23000, 52001, 52001, 2020-01-27, 2020-01-27]
TARGET: [23000, 52001, 52001, 2020-01-27, 2020-01-27]
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it too much problem dealing with dtypes before? Try to use df[column] = df[column].astype(int)

Comment: I have 31 columns. They are all of different dtypes (varchar, date, number). and the columns being passed to my comparison logic will keep on changing. Can i change all date columns to int without loosing any data?

Comment: Also can someone tell me why comparison using == does not work in this case? I have read that == does value comparison , so it should work, but it doesn't seem to. Any ideas?